# Syinc databases mySQL to Oracle

Tags: mysql-5.6, data-synchronization, oracle-8i

I'm new in "databaase administration"
the problem I am facing is that I want to have an exact copy of a table, from `MySQL` database (website database) to `oracle` database (a local one).

**What I've done till now**

Searched for two days.

I installed `MySQL connector/odbc` on the 'oracle machine' and successfully connected to the remote MySQL database

Also I can execute queries from the oracle machine like:

```
select * from remote_table;
```

and it shows the expected results,

**The problem here is:**
Is there a way to sync these two databases (mySQL to oracle), or at least update the local one every midnight..

**About the two machines**

Both machines are running Windows OS

**local one :**
Running Windows XP
Oracle 8i

**remote one :** 
Running Windows 8.1
MySql 5.6.17

Answer (score 0):

well i created a small program using java packages :

[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)

and aoracle jdbc driver :

[classes12.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-10201-088211.html) (this version for oracle 8i)

with mysql connector i can run a "select" statements an read from mysql databse, and then i build an "insert" statement to instert them in the oracle database.

this was the best solution i found